# java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() Error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, handler

[SongList Code in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh8Dz.png)Not able to understand what actually the error is and why it is caused.Error shown shown below.

```
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:754)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ListActivity.<init>(ListActivity.java:175)
W/System.err:     at com.example.vipul.finalproject.PlayListActivity.<init>(PlayListActivity.java:0)
W/System.err:     at com.example.vipul.finalproject.SongList.scanSongs(SongList.java:296)
W/System.err:     at com.example.vipul.finalproject.activities.ActivityMenuMain$ScanSongs.doInBackground(ActivityMenuMain.java:299)
W/System.err:     at com.example.vipul.finalproject.activities.ActivityMenuMain$ScanSongs.doInBackground(ActivityMenuMain.java:289)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[The best explanation on why](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYDJH6tDyNg&t=216s) you need a looper on one thread to save instructions and another thread to execute them. In a multi thread application task may come while executing other task.

Comment: Please, read my comment in my answer. Your answer is not addressing the question, plus your answer consists of a link with almost no explanation.

Answer (score 2):

See [this article](https://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/) to understand the whole `Looper`/`Handler` relationship.

Long story short, your `Thread#run()` method must follow a structure like so:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        mHandler = new Handler();
        Looper.loop();
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Ok, now that you're sharing the whole stack trace, I see that your problem seems that you're trying to create an `Activity` (`PlayListActivity`) in SongList.java:296. You cannot create an `Activity` using `new` (i.e. manually creating an `Activity` is not allowed, you need to use an `Intent`). Can you share `SongList#scanSongs()` method around line 296?

Comment: Image is added for SongList

Comment: 1. Code doesn't match with stack trace. Are you sure this is the code that it's being executed? Try rebuilding, just in case. 2. It is not very nice to paste an image instead of code, it makes checking it much harder.

Comment: Why would you ask where to place code if you don't show your code?

Comment: I mean pasting the actual code (text) instead of a screenshot.